# LaTex front page design using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, titles

to enhance the looks of my front page I would like to add wavy forms.
I tried using Tikz but I could not make it work.

I am looking to make a design that looks like this:
[image]

The code I use to make my front page is as following:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\epigraphflush{flushright}
\renewcommand\epigraphsize{\normalsize}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{0.7\textwidth}

\DeclareFixedFont{\titlefont}{T1}{ppl}{b}{it}{0.5in}

\makeatletter                       
\def\printauthor{%                  
{\large \@author}}              
\makeatother
\author{%
Author 1 name \\
Department name \\
\texttt{email1@example.com}\vspace{20pt} \\
Author 2 name \\
Department name \\
\texttt{email2@example.com}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\noindent
\titlefont \center PROFIBUS \\of\\ PROFINET?\par
\Large{Argumenten voor de implementatie van communicatie protocollen}%
\null\vfill
\vspace*{1cm}
\noindent
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
    \printauthor
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.02\linewidth}
\rule{1pt}{125pt}
\end{minipage}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me realize the image I have in my head?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't want to sound mean, but do you really think this enhances the looks of your titlepage?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: To center some stuff, you should not use `\center` but `\centering` or put it inside a `center`-*environment* (`\begin{center} ... \end{center}`).

Answer (score 5):

Another solution with `tikzmark` and `hobby` libraries. Don't watch the result but the idea ;-)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,hobby}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\epigraphflush{flushright}
\renewcommand\epigraphsize{\normalsize}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{0.7\textwidth}

\DeclareFixedFont{\titlefont}{T1}{ppl}{b}{it}{0.5in}

\makeatletter                       
\def\printauthor{%                  
{\large \@author}}              
\makeatother
\author{%
Author 1 name \\
Department name \\
\texttt{email1@example.com}\vspace{20pt} \\
Author 2 name \\
Department name \\
\texttt{email2@example.com}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\noindent
\titlefont \center \tikzmark{a}PROFIBUS \\of\\ PROFINET?\tikzmark{b}\par
\Large{Argumenten voor de implementatie van communicatie protocollen}%
\null\vfill
\vspace*{1cm}
\noindent
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
    \printauthor
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.02\linewidth}
\rule{1pt}{125pt}
\end{minipage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\begin{scope}[shift=(pic cs:a)]
\draw[line width=3mm, blue!70!black] (0,0) to[curve through={(-.5,.25) (-1,.55) (-.75,.75) (-.5,1.5)}] (-2,2);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[shift=(pic cs:b)]
\draw[line width=3mm, green!70!black] (0,0) to[curve through={(1,.5) (1.5,1.5) (2.5,2.5) (2,3)}] (3.5,3.8);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\tikzmark` to put marks next to the appropiate words in the title, use `(current page)` node to refer to the appropriate corners of the page, and relative `control` points to distort the line joining those points. For the green path an intermediate coordinate is required, to create the "double wave" in the path.

All togheter:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\renewcommand\epigraphflush{flushright}
\renewcommand\epigraphsize{\normalsize}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{0.7\textwidth}

\DeclareFixedFont{\titlefont}{T1}{ppl}{b}{it}{0.5in}

\makeatletter                       
\def\printauthor{%                  
{\large \@author}}              
\makeatother
\author{%
Author 1 name \\
Department name \\
\texttt{email1@example.com}\vspace{20pt} \\
Author 2 name \\
Department name \\
\texttt{email2@example.com}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\noindent
\titlefont \center \tikzmark{B}PROFIBUS \\of\\ PROFINET?\tikzmark{N}\par
\Large{Argumenten voor de implementatie van communicatie protocollen}%
\null\vfill
\vspace*{1cm}
\noindent
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
    \printauthor
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.02\linewidth}
\rule{1pt}{125pt}
\end{minipage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\draw[violet!70, line width=2ex] (current page.north west) .. controls +(10,-3) and  +(-10,1) .. ($(B)+(0,0.5)$);
\coordinate (aux) at ($(N)!.5!(current page.north east)$);
\draw[green!70!white!80!black, line width=2ex] ($(N)+(0.2,0.5)$) .. controls +(7,2) and +(-5,-1) .. (aux)
    .. controls +(5,1) and +(-8, -3) .. (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

You could play with `controls`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\epigraphflush{flushright}
\renewcommand\epigraphsize{\normalsize}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{0.7\textwidth}

\DeclareFixedFont{\titlefont}{T1}{ppl}{b}{it}{0.5in}

\makeatletter                       
\def\printauthor{%                  
{\large \@author}}              
\makeatother
\author{%
Author 1 name \\
Department name \\
\texttt{email1@example.com}\vspace{20pt} \\
Author 2 name \\
Department name \\
\texttt{email2@example.com}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[line width=5pt,color=green!75!black] (-1,1) .. controls (0,2) and
    (0.5,-2) .. (1,-2) .. controls (1.6,-2) and (1.5,-1)
    .. (2,-1);
end{tikzpicture}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\noindent
\titlefont \center PROFIBUS \\of\\ PROFINET?\par
\Large{Argumenten voor de implementatie van communicatie protocollen}%
\null\vfill
\vspace*{1cm}
\noindent
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
    \printauthor
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}{0.02\linewidth}
\rule{1pt}{125pt}
\end{minipage}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]